# Continuous Compounding vs Discrete Compounding

Tags: calculus

> A deposit of 10000 euros was made. After 5 years it yielded 1314.8
>   euros. What was the interest rate? Show your answer as a percentage,
>   with 1 decimal case.

To solve this I did this 2 ways:

Using Continuous Compounding:
$$11314.8 = 10000 \cdot e^{5x} \Leftrightarrow x \approx .0247$$

Using Discrete Compounding:
$$10000\cdot (1+k)^5 = 11314.8 \Leftrightarrow x \approx .025$$

Either of them are equal to $2.5$%, but which one is more appropriate for this problem, discrete our countinuous compounding?

I think it should be discrete conpounding because there is a fixed time for the interest to be gained. In this case, I think the right one is the discrete one. Is this correct?

Comment: I think that whoever wrote the question should make it clear what kind of compounding, if any, is intended. Maybe you're supposed to get it from context, from whatever else is on the same page or in the same section as the question. In any event, I'd recommend asking the person who is setting the problem, if that's possible.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It's from my schoolbook. That's all they say.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think I am supposed to deduce it is the discrete compound because there is an example on the same page that uses that formula... it's ridiculous

Comment: I'd recommend asking your teacher then.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't really have one right now. But we are getting off-topic here